# "on the paper" vs "on top of the paper"

Tags: meaning, prepositions

I have read a chapter on prepositions of place in a teaching manual entitled "Trainers Treasure" The author is Seth Lindstromberg and it was published in ELT JOURNAL, OUP volume 50/3, July 1996 under the title  "Prepositions: Meaning and Method

It was explained that 'on' is usually used for things which are flat such as paper. On the other hand, 'on top of' is used usually for things which are tall or vertical such as bottle.

we say:

**1.** There is a pen ***on*** the paper

**2.** There is a coin ***on top of*** the bottle.

**3.** There is a label ***on***  the bottle

I would like to know whether we can say:

> 1. There is a pen *on top of* the paper.

If yes, what is the context in which it can be used?

Can we say the following since the coin is placed *on the lid*?

> 2. The coin is *on* the bottle

Comment: I do not know why this question be closed.it is neither duplicate nor is it off the topic.It is not good on the part of the users with high reputation to vote for closing

Comment: Two users voted to migrate it over to ELL. Now, if you included the link to the actual source, it would be viewed more favourably. You have some good questions and sources, but on EL&U people expect links and citations (and proper formatting too).

Comment: Marie-Lou A Even your comments are being deleted.I do not think it is a question for ElL.we can not ask good questions all the time.Yes I have a problem with formating.I wil over come the problem soon

Comment: That was a bad mistake on my part. The issue has since been cleared up. As for this question, it's well thought out and presented. Just the formatting: italics, bold (try not to go overboard with the bold), spaces, numbered list etc. leaves a bit to be desired.

Comment: Marie-Lou A  I think my question has not been answered satisfactorily

Comment: I believe the author you are referring to is Seth Lindstromberg, not Seth Lind Stromberg.

Comment: No I am correct.The article is on PDF file.I would have added the link if it is accessible

Comment: Jagatha V L Narasimharao: unless you learn that not everything we read / hear / yes, even think ... is inerrant, you will encounter vast problems. 6 results for the typo 'Seth Lind Stromberg' in a Google search, but 18 000 (rounded) for the accurate 'Seth Lindstromberg'. And though not all may agree with everything posted here by DJClayworth,  he is a respected and scholarly contributor here.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth.Anyhow.The article is there on the PDF file.In my book and in the google search I found his name as I mentioned.I do not think he is wrong.If I am wrong, the author is wrong too

Comment: Here, (4) is a distractor, as, essentially, is the metaphorical usage 'a label on the bottle' (compare 'on the wall', 'on the train', and ultimately, perhaps, 'on fire'). // One expects superposition with common items with horizontal surfaces like tables, shelves, chairs, beds, and even books, [news]papers, [pads of] paper....  However, with less usual locations, 'on top of' tends to be favoured: on top of the filing cabinet,  pile of CDs, laundry basket, [bottle?], biscuit tin.... / With 'not exactly on top of' situations (on the stand, on the hook ...), 'on' is the usual choice.

Comment: I do not think SethLindstromberg is "wrong" in the sense of having made a mistake. I think he is providing a simple rule for English teachers to give their students to help them decide if "on" or "on top of" is best. It works most of the time. But since the question then asks about more advanced usages, I provided an answer that I believe more accurately explains when a native English speaker would use 'on top of". I hope that Seth Lindstromberg would not disagree with me.

Comment: @DJClayworth I believe that the images used to illustrate the meanings of "on" and "on top of" are a springboard to then teach the meanings of "come on" and to "be on top of something" e.g. *game* compared to "be under something" e.g. *stress*. It's a good article, a bit "windy" for my liking, but some good teaching ***tips***. The paper is not about grammar, it's about conveying the sense of prepositions and phrasal verbs (*come on*, *come back*) and making it more real and meaningful for learners.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I completely agree. I probably should have written "he is providing guidance" rather than "he is providing a simple rule".

Comment: Quoting from the pdf file “explain that we can use *on top of* **concerning flat things for special emphasis** when we want to be extra definite, e.g. 'No! Not under the paper. *On top of* it!' ”

Comment: I don't think this should have been migrated.

Comment: @DJClayworth Thank you very much.My question has been migrated eventhough I showed the source and the question is not  of  a very low level

Answer (score 3):

Using "on" for flat things and "on top of" for tall things is not a hard and fast rule. It may be attempting to provide a starting point for people new to English, but it does not apply in all cases. You could say "the loudspeaker is on the speaker stand" even though the speaker stand is very tall and thin. Also "The book is on the stool".

[Lindstromberg writes](http://www.sethlindstromberg.info/uploads/articles/Prepositions%20Meaning%20and%20Method.pdf) (page 231) in his advice on teaching prepositions: "Demonstrate or draw, for example, 'on the paper' and 'on top of the bottle'. Show that we can also say 'on the bottle', but add that on top of is what we often say for tall things.". The key word is "often". Native speakers do *often* say that, but it is a not a rule, and not what exclusively determines the use of "on top of".  Lindstromberg is not trying to explain definitively the use prepositions, he is writing about how to effectively teach the general use of prepositions.

A better way to think about this is that "on top of" is used mainly where "on" might have an unclear meaning. With the case of the paper, "on the paper" might well mean "drawn on the paper", so if there is any danger of confusion you say "on top of". But if someone asks "where did I leave my pen" you can say "your pen is on the paper" without any danger of confusion, so you do.

Likewise "the label is on the bottle" generally means it is attached to the bottle on its flat vertical side. If the label is really resting on the top of the bottle, you would use "on top of" to avoid confusion. This is probably where your author gets his rule from. Many tall thin things can have objects "on" their sides (like a label on a bottle), so if you want to make it clear that the label is sitting on the top of the bottle you would say "on top of".

To answer your specific question, it is grammatically correct to say "the pen is on top of the paper", but most English speakers would not use it unless there was a possibility of being misunderstood. If you were referring to a picture resting on the paper you might say "the picture is on top of the paper" to distinguish from the case where the picture might be *drawn* on the paper. If the pen was right at the top of a big pile of paper you might say "the pen is on top of the paper" to distinguish it from the case where the pen is on some other part of the pile.

**TLDR: Use "on top of" when "on" might be misunderstood.** Or possibly for emphasis.

Comment: The Journal is not meant for the learners of English, it is used by the reputed Instititutes like The English and Foreign language University.Besides, Seth Lind Stormberg is a reputed Native English speaker and writer of many books and articles

Comment: I have no explanation for what he wrote, but the rule you quote is definitely wrong. English speakers do not say "on top of something" just because the something is tall and thin. They might say it if the thing normally has things "on" it that are somewhere other than the top, but that is not the same thing. maybe you could quote the entire passage of the article where you found this rule?

Comment: @ DJClayworth The author is from England. you are from canada.you native speakers  do not use English the same way.you disagree with one another we non native speakers follow the rules written by the British authors.I don't think the author is wrong

Comment: I'm a native British English speaker. Also you should be clear that there are no definitive rules for speaking English (unlike French). If you wish to follow some rules that someone has made up, go ahead, but don't expect to sound like a native speaker when you do.

Comment: I hope you will read his article.we are losing faith in the books written by native English authors because you contradict one anotherHe has shown the example with illustrations.

Comment: I would be happy to read his article if you provide a link. Or if you would copy the relevant paragraph into the question (which it is legal to do) that would be good too. And the reason we contradict each other is *because* English does not have hard and fast rules.

Comment: @DJclayworth.You have edited your answer.First you said that it was wrong. What do you mean by do not sound like a native speaker? is it a warning for me or do you think that non native speakers can not use good English.

Comment: [This](http://www.sethlindstromberg.info/uploads/articles/Prepositions%20Meaning%20and%20Method.pdf) is a link to the cited article by Lindstormberg, in which he sets forth a novel (then) approach to teaching the idea of a preposition, and an attempt to rationalise different related usages. He certainly states that 'on top of' is often used for tall objects (I'd also add the 'unfamiliar placings' factor). I don't think the 'on top of the bottle' example is well chosen. Too contrived / artificial ... heading towards silly. I'd use 'A statue of Nelson, on top of 'his' column' (with picture).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks for that. The situation is exactly what I thought. Lindstromberg writes: "Demonstrate or draw, for example, 'on the paper' and 'on top of the bottle'. Show that we can also say 'on the bottle', but add that on
top of is what we often say for tall things.". The key word is "often". We do "often" say that, but it is not a rule.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth.I did not say that it was a rule.I used the word usually.It means often or more than often .I think  some of the native speakers have a tendency to look down upon the non native speakers instead of encoraging them.Infact, English is a language of fewer rules and more exceptions.

Comment: One place (!) where 'on' and 'on top of' can have very different meanings, though the substrate (referent) is the same, is 'She is on the mountain' / 'She is on top of the mountain'. Unlike the 'on the bottle' / 'on top of the bottle' (rather a strange concept) cases, these have hypernymic rather than contradictory (with the usual sense of 'on the bottle', as with a label, meant) relation.

Comment: A much better example than my pile of paper.